# Looking for segment data in hls output from ffmpeg

Tags: go, ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

Just as the title states. I'm trying to find the raw data that usually gets written to the .ts files. However I don't want to create a playlist or have these files written to disk i any way. I would rather buffer the ffmpeg output and try to somehow parse it to get the same content.

am I going in the wrong direction with this? Should I be looking for something representing mpgets headers?

So far this is what I've come up with.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os/exec"
    "strings"
    "testing"
)

func TestExtractor(t *testing.T) {
    args := "-i https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4 -c:v libx264 -crf 21 -preset veryfast -g 25 -sc_threshold 0 -c:a aac -b:a 128k -ac 2 -f hls -sc_threshold 0 -hls_segment_type mpegts -hls_time 2 -"

    cmd := exec.Command("ffmpeg", strings.Split(args, " ")...)
    // Create a pipe to read the FFmpeg output.
    stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    s := []byte{
        // Offset 0x0004A543 to 0x0004A5D9
        255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
        255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
        255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
        255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
        255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
        255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
        255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
        255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
        255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
        255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
        255}

    buffer := make([]byte, len(s))

    for {
        n, err := stdout.Read(buffer)
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        }

        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        if bytes.Equal(buffer[:n], s) {
            log.Printf("\nFOUND BUFFER \n %v \n ============= \b", buffer[:n])
        } else {
            //log.Printf("\nNOT FOUND BUFFER \n %v \n ============= \b", buffer[:n])
        }
    }
    if err := cmd.Wait(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: ` if bytes.Equal(buffer[:n], s)` You assume buf is going to be filled by exactly the amount of 0xFF that you use to fill `s`.  In the context of a for loop until EOF, it seems unlikely all you'll read from `stdout` until `EOF` is reads of 151 `0xFF` bytes at a time.

Comment: 151 0xFF bytes was what I’ve managed to find in the output. See this exact amount of bytes with the same value means something. The problem is that I can’t know what they mean until I understand what the hls specs. Are, how many bytes to read and where the different sections begin.